# Spring MVC spring:bind tag

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

Trying to get hold of `<spring:bind>` tag. I am trying to print a String value. The code looks something like:

```
  mySimpleBean myBean = presentStudent.getSubjects().getTeacherName();
    String firstName = myBean.getTeacherFirstName()
```

Where I get "myBean" from another bean "presentStudent". On jsp I am trying:

```
  <spring:bind path="presentStudent.subjects.teacherName.teacherFirstName">
    <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
```

But it doesnt print anything. 
       Also "presentStudent" is commandObject for this form:

```
<form:form id="stuTeachForm" name="stuTeachForm" method="post" commandName="presentStudent"
    action="getStuTeachData.html">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sping input tag instead of the bind tag

```
<form:form id="stuTeachForm" name="stuTeachForm" method="post" commandName="presentStudent" action="getStuTeachData.html">
   <form:input type="text" path="subjects.teacherName.teacherFirstName"/>
```

Might also be worth outputting the desired value to check your bean  has been properly populated

```
First name is ${presentStudent.subjects.teacherName.teacherFirstName}
```